# How we convert emoji into to emoticon or text in all dataset

Tags: python-3.x

“How we convert emoji into to emoticon or text in all dataset. I have a 20000 example in my dataset. In every example there are emoji. I want to find the emotion in the dataset using emoji can anyone guide me how i do this? How all that emoji convert into text.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python package called `emoji`, which seems to do the job of converting the emoji to its corresponding text.

Assuming you are using Python 3, you can install it using `pip`, it doesn't exist on Anaconda's main channel.

```
from emoji.unicode_codes import UNICODE_EMOJI

emoji = ''

print(UNICODE_EMOJI[emoji])
```

The above code prints out:

```
:smiling_face_with_smiling_eyes:
```

The key point to note here is, `UNICODE_EMOJI` is a dictionary and you should only send it the emoji as the key.

Comment: i want to convert all emoji into emoticon or text how i can do this with this library

Comment: You can create a list of entire emojis and get the corresponding texts using the above method, and then store the (emoji, text) as a dictionary.